# How is the best way to debug an AppArmor syntax error?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, apparmor

**Recently I upgraded Debian, from Stretch (v9x) to Buster (v10.2).**

Now in **Thunderbird** (package v68.3.0) when I click a link in an email, my browser (FireFox, v71.0, downloaded, i.e. not packaged) **won't open a clicked hyper link.**

---

I'm seeking advise on how to properly fix AppArmor profiles to reasonably work with this newer FireFox.

In other words, if I say `$ aa-complain /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird` this makes email links work again, and FireFox now opens properly.** (Now this workaround is also broken 2021/05).  But it leaves a security hole in AppArmor that I want to fix, if I can.

*(I realize that if I had installed the package version of FireFox, rather than the most recent version downloaded from FireFox, that I probably wouldn't have this issue.  But I want to have more recent software at times, as I think the most recent version is more likely to be more fully patched in terms of bugs and it's own security holes.)*

---

Here's what I've learned and tried.

1. **Thunderbird has 3 entry points:**

   /usr/bin/thunderbird  (a smaller executable)

   /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird (a link to the following)
   /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird-bin (a large executable)

My Cinnamon Menu opens the one in /usr/bin/thunderbird, but this seems to call /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird-bin.

2. **But thunderbird has only one AppArmor profile:**

   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird

which contains this line `#include <abstractions/ubuntu-browsers>`, or in other words including this profile file:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers
```

which then has these two lines relating to **firefox**:

```
/usr/bin/firefox Cxr -> sanitized_helper,
/usr/lib{,64}/firefox*/firefox* Cx -> sanitized_helper,
```

3. **But I don't yet have a firefox AppArmor profile.**

So to ignore the missing FireFox profile, I tried changing these last two lines to this:

```
/opt/firefox/firefox ux,
```

or this:

```
/opt/firefox/firefox Uxr -> sanitized_helper,
```

but AppArmor is still not happy, as I'm seeing this error:

```
$ aa-complain /usr/bin/firefox
Setting /usr/bin/thunderbird to complain mode.

ERROR: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird doesn't contain a valid profile for /usr/bin/thunderbird (syntax error?)
```

---

**My questions:**

**How is the best way to start to find and fix this AppArmor syntax error** (if that's what it is) in my profiles?

I tried commenting out (removing) sections of ubuntu-browsers but that didn't seem to help.

I also tried running `$ /etc/init.d/apparmor restart` which succeeds, but still the above error doesn't go away.

I also tried running `apparmor_parser --replace -d usr.bin.thunderbird` but I get lost in the output.

Comment: But now my workaround described above is also unfortunately broken!  ".. if I say $ aa-complain /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird this makes email links work again, and FireFox now opens properly."

Comment: `ERROR: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird doesn't contain a valid profile for /usr/bin/thunderbird (syntax error?)` becacuse you should `aa-complain /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird`, not `/usr/bin/thunderbird`

Comment: To solve the problem of web link in Thunderbird in Debian bookworm, see my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/740899/38242

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error. You complained the wrong executable. You should complain `/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird` instead of `/usr/bin/thunderbird`:

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
```