# web links broken again in thunderbird 78.11.0 on Debian

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, links

Anyone know how to get the latest Thunderbird working with the latest Firefox on Linux, so that when you click on a link in an email a browser tab opens the selected URL?

In the recent Thunderbird 78.11.0 update web links stopped working again for me on Debian 10.

In previous Thunderbird versions I was able to change Apparmor to **complain mode** to make links work property.

*Also note that there are LOTS of old fixes for this found from a web search that don't apply because they are outdated, but still linger on the web.*

*(I am aware of the tradoff between using the latest version of thunderbird, and using an older package version of thunderbird with known bugs in it, but that might not stumble over apparmor issues.  Hopefully someday the latest version will also come with an appropriate apparmor profile so that we don't have to choose between old and new.)*

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird change this line as follows:

```
#/opt/firefox/firefox Cx,   -was, to:

/opt/firefox/firefox r,     # This allows Thunderbird to open links in Firefox
```

THEN restart apparmor with this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart   # to reload it.
```

Comment: After upgrade to Debian Bullseye this is again broken.  :-(

And now this fix doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the web link problem in thunderbird 102.9 in bookworm.

Go to Thunderbird's settings page. In the "General" tab, find the list "Files & Attachments". Search for `http` and `https`. In the dropdown box, choose "Delete Action".

Finally, `aa-complain` thunderbird:

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
```